# How to use JavaScript to load and get XML from url

Tags: javascript, xml

I am a new java script developer and have a problem ,  the source below to get the weather by XML , it is working well with a local XML file in the same folder of the source code file, but when i change "weather.xml" with "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=Iraq&format=xml&num_of_days=1&key=9y735qqycg2gzsds7nbx6y5f" where i want to get XML from it is not working , any body can help please ?...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;     
        txt1=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("weatherDesc")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        txt2=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("temp_C")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        txt3=txt1+txt2+"°C";
        document.write(txt3);
    }
} 
xmlhttp.open("GET","weather.xml",true);
xmlhttp.send();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would recommend you make yourself familiar with a JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) or similar which simplify such tasks (see http://learn.jquery.com/ and specifically for your question: http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/).

Comment: Thanks for answer , but I am wondering why it is working with local XML file , but when i change to URL it is not.

Comment: Might be the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) but I'm not sure.

Comment: You need to use JSONP which really is more complicated using pure js than if you use the built in jquery ajax methods.  JQuery just makes javascript more manageable across platforms so you don't need to worry as much about cross-browser support.

Comment: Thanks , i am already reading about that in jQuery  now.

Comment: "code for IE6, IE5" IE5?!